# Dense Rank or number by group by condition ignoring values that don't meet condition

Tags: r, dense-rank

I have data set example below:

```
name   date           value1 

grape  01-01-2018     127

grape  01-02-2018     124

grape  01-03-2018     154

grape  01-04-2018        

grape  01-05-2018     123

pear   01-01-2018     324

pear   01-02-2018     374

pear   01-03-2018        

pear   01-04-2018     312
```

**Desired output:**

```
name   date          value1 producing days

grape  01-01-2018     127      1

grape  01-02-2018     124      2

grape  01-03-2018     154      3

grape  01-04-2018               

grape  01-05-2018     123      4

pear   01-01-2018     324      1

pear   01-02-2018     374      2

pear   01-03-2018               

pear   01-04-2018     312      3
```

I have tried:

```
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(NAME) %>% 
  mutate(Producing_Days = dense_rank(Date))
```

I have tried

```
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(NAME) %>% 
  mutate(Producing_Days = dense_rank(Date))
```

and seq along and nrow but i cannot get them to skip the days that have no value

Comment: Do you intend to keep the days with no value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: You can replace `is.na` with `value1==""`

Final answer after suggestions from   @ demarsylvain

```
 df %>% group_by(name) %>% 
 mutate(Producing_days = ifelse(is.na(value1), NA,as.character(Date)) %>% 
          dense_rank())
```

Comment: if you use `dense_rank()` on the variable Date, you will have 5 counts for the group grap (instead of 4 as desired). You should create a variable where value is missing when you don't want to count the row.

`df %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(Producing_days = ifelse(is.na(value1), NA, as.character(Date)) %>% dense_rank())`

Comment: Im sorry I would also like to add that i also was looking for ranking/numbering based of value 1 being greater than a value say 125 so the numbering would just ignore those rows and then just number the next row that met the condition in the group

Comment: The answer provide by demarsylvain is correct.  I could also chang the is.na to value 1 <125 and the numbering was correct and as expected.  Thank you all for your quick replies.  I will now try to go through the code and understand why it has to be written this way with dense rank on the end after after its own pipe operator

Comment: `df %>% mutate(temporary = ifelse(is.na(value1), NA, as.character(Date)) %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(Producing_days = dense_rank(temporary))`
dense_rank on the end after a pipe is the same thing same dense_rank at the beginning, it is just another way to write it.